# Add the center points of a cluster in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For training purposes I want to create a Shiny application that outlines the steps in a KNN algorithm. The first step I want to is show is the center of two clusters.

I use ggplot to first show the Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width of the iris dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width))
g + geom_point()
```

Then I randomly assign a cluster to the set:

```
iris$Cluster <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(iris)){
  randInt <- x1 <- round(runif(1, 0, 1),0)
  ifelse(randInt == 0,iris$Cluster[i] <- 1, iris$Cluster[i] <- 0)
}
iris$Cluster <- as.factor(iris$Cluster)                               
g <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width, colour = Cluster))
g + geom_point()
```

Now the next step I want to take is to show a dot in my plot that is the center of cluster 0 and cluster 1.

Any thoughts on how I can do this in ggplot2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the centroid of each cluster on the fly within a second call to `geom_point`. Here's an example using `tidyverse` functions. We calculate the mean of `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` within each cluster and plot these mean values using crosses as the point markers. Note also that you shouldn't restate the data frame name within `aes`, but should instead use column names alone.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Assign random cluster value
iris$cluster = sample(0:1, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, colour=factor(cluster))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=iris %>% 
               group_by(cluster) %>% 
               summarise_at(vars(matches("Sepal")), mean),
             size=5, shape=3) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In base R (apart from `ggplot2`) we can do:

```
library(ggplot2)

iris$Cluster <- as.factor(rbinom(nrow(iris), 1, .5))  # more convenient

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, colour=Cluster)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aggregate(iris, by=list(Cluster=iris$Cluster), mean)[, 1:3], 
             size=10, shape=3) +
  theme_bw() + labs(x="Sepal Length", y="Sepal Width", color="Cluster Type")
```

## Yields:

[image]